# Some of attributes are missing from the element found by Selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to grab the location of an image from a website with Selenium. Here is my code:

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();        
    driver.get("http://mini.imbc.com/index.html?service=onair&channel=mfm");
    WebElement dynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 300)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='viewer bg-black30']/img")));
    System.out.println(dynamicElement.getAttribute("outerHTML"));        
    driver.quit();
```

This is what I get with the code above:

```
<img width="298" height="168">
```

However, the following is what the `img` element actually is when I look at the page's DOM:

```
<img width="298" height="168" src="http://img.imbc.com/adams/Program/20149/130555114063940358_Big_C.png">
```

How can I get the element with all its attributes?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `img` element starts without the `src` attribute and gets it added later by some JavaScript code. If you change your XPath expression to add `[@src]`:

```
//div[@class='viewer bg-black30']/img[@src]
```

then Selenium will wait until the `img` element has an `src` attribute. I've tested it here and it works.

Comment: +1 really good to know that it would wait for an attribute to exist.

Comment: Awesome! 
Can you guess why the htmlunitdriver version doesn't work?
ChromeDriver() ==> HtmlUnitDriver(true)

Comment: @user2981822 The edit you made to your question and what you are asking here is a significantly *different* question. If you edit your initial question to add a different question to it, this is a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/241526). Chameleon questions are not something we want on SO. What you should do is search SO to see if your *new* question was asked, and then if not asked already, post a question in which you explain that you are trying to figure out why the code that works with `ChromeDriver` does not work with `HtmlUnitDriver`. I'm going to roll back you

Comment: @user2981822 Oops... sorry. The editing system cut off my previous comment. I meant to finish with "I'm going to roll back *your question*." So that it is no longer a chameleon question. Feel free to search and post a new question like I described in my previous comment.